# when i have multiple python files in pycharm it gives errors

Tags: python, random, pycharm, attributeerror

i've been going through some tutorials and have been actively taking notes whilst watching the videos and copying the code. Which has resulted in having multiple python files in my pycharm projects.

I have noticed that when i reach a certain number of files the terminal returns back errors but when the code is run a new project folder it runs perfectly fine.

Not sure why that is, has anyone got any ideas?
Also should i be creating multiple python files when learning?

**This is an example of an error:**

Code:

```
import random

value = random.randint(1, 6)
print(value)
```

error:

```
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'
```

But when run in a new project it works...

Comment: Did you name one of your files random.py?

Comment: One of your files is called `random.py`, so Python imports it instead of the standard module

Comment: How many files do you have, because you should have a lot of files, because I have used about a hundred files in pycharm with a lot of code in them, and have not had a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Comment: I made a newbie error and named my file random. Thanks for the help everyone else. Not sure why it was down voted... The last time it didnt work was probably because i called my file 'json'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [random.randint error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178648/random-randint-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have another script called random? It might be trying to import .randint() from there.

Comment: I made a newbie error and named my file random. Thanks for the help everyone else. Not sure why it was down voted... The last time it didnt work was probably because i called my file 'json'.